# JTable - ActionListener for select a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, actionlistener

I need the right `AcionListener` for my `JTable`.

At program start there is no row selected by default. If I now select any row in this `JTable` then the `ActionListener` shall start.

Comment: Do you ***see*** an `addActionListener(..)` method in [The Fine Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)?  What 'add listener' methods *do* you see?

Answer (score 26):

Try this. I use a `ListSelectionListener` and it works for me. I added a listener to the table Model

```
jTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        if (jTable.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
            // print first column value from selected row
            System.out.println(jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: basically correct, though: a) in a real-world context you most probably would want to check for isValueAdjusting b) the value might be null

Comment: `the value might be null`, she means to test `if(selectedRow > -1)`, required, otherwise you can to kill JTables view with endless loop from exceptions that can freeze Swing GUI

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @mKorbel good catch - but yet another than I meant :-)

Comment: Where should i place this? In the main of the Jframe class or somewhere else?

Comment: This worked for me.